# No import module named records when importing project from Git in pydev

Tags: python, django, eclipse, git

I'm using eclipse with pydev and I get a project from a git repository. There was not a .project so I imported it as a general project. I set it as django project and I can run it, but when I try to open a shell with django environment, I says that

```
"ImportError: No module named 'back'"
```

where `back` is the name of my project.

When I imported the project, it was put in the `C:/username/git`, while eclpise works in the `C:/username/workspace`. Do you this this is the reason of the error ? Is it related to `PYTHONPATH` ? How to know it ?

Comment: Please start with the help for PyDev http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_project_conf.html (see the bottom section titled "Creating a Project from existing sources" and perhaps someone can answer a more narrow question?

Comment: Thank you Jonah, the page after the one you sent was useful. It was a PYTHONPATH issue, I had to add the src folder of the project to it.